How can I fix pycham wrong django type hint
from django.db.models import QuerySet

member_meta_models: QuerySet[MemberWantedMetaModel] = MemberWantedMetaModel.objects.filter(member_id=member_id)

Pycharm says
Expected type QuerySet[MemberWantedMetaModel,MemberWantedMetaModel], got QuerySet[MemberWantedMetaModel]

I think type hint is right.
How Can I fix it.
If my type hint is wrong, How can I fix it?
(I am using python 3.13.0, Django 5.1.4 mypy, pydantic, django-stubs)
Thanks

Your code is incomplete. Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example
